# MySql - Two tables with different casing

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, create-table

I would like to create two tables:

- mytable
- MyTable

I am using Navicat to create those tables. The problem is, I can't create both because after one has been created, it says that the database already exists.

I checked on StackOverflow and find each times people speaking about set up `lower_case_table_names = 2` and restart MySQL server but still the issues is firing.
I've tested on a MySQL Linux server and it works properly...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: in MySQL table name is file name. on Linux case of file names on disk different. On windows file names is case insensetive.

Comment: Why the heck could you want to have 2 tables with the same name in the same schema?! This way your design becomes completely self-explanatory, right? :)

Comment: Seriously consider how flawed this idea is.